# Creating a link to an application?

Tags: linux

Would like to do this: Make terminal command do the same like lxterminal.
So I think i will need to create a link to it.

```
ln -s lxterminal terminal
```

this doesnt work, maybe I need to trace where the lxterminal is, but how?

Comment: Hi, this question is better suited (and maybe answered) here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question should be migrated to http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have (at least) two options.

- Create a symbolic link:

  ```
  ln -s $(which lxterminal) /path/to/terminal
  ```
- Create an *alias*:

  ```
  alias terminal='lxterminal'
  ```

Both options make the assumption that `lxterminal` is in your `${PATH}`.

The symbolic link approach requires write access to the placeholder "`/path/to`" (`${HOME}/bin` or some such) and for this to be in your `${PATH}` too. This is the more robust solution, but the alias may suffice if you just want to save typing at the prompt.